# Which HSV-noise values do not cause artifacts on an LCD screen?

Tags: website-design, gimp, filter, visual-artifacts

I have come to notice that certain HSV noise filter values applied to a uniform background colour look horrible when viewed on an LCD screen under certain viewing angles. This is more noticeable on (cheap?) laptop/notebook screens.

Here are two contrasting specimen, made with the [GIMP HSV noise filter](http://docs.gimp.org/2.8/en/plug-in-hsv-noise.html) for the RGB colour #F3F3E9.

Below background becomes coarsely grained and patchy on LCD screens under certain viewing angles. It was created by applying the HSV noise filter with the following parameters:

```
- Holdness = 2
- Hue = 0
- Saturation = 0
- Value = 14
```

[image: 2.0.0.14]

Below background is less offending. However, on an analogue CRT screen the grain becomes barely visible. GIMP HSV noise filter parameters are:

```
- Holdness = 4
- Hue = 3
- Saturation = 13
- Value = 13
```

[image: 4.3.13.13]

Comment: I think the fact the pattern is created with GIMP here is irrelevant - what you want to know is the efffects/looks of grainy images on LCD screens. I think that if you retag your question, omtting GIMP altogether, and things like "LCD", "artifact", you would have a better chance of getting a meaningful answer. (even if not the exact values to use in this specific GIMP filter)

Comment: @jsbueno Thanks! I have edited my question following your clues. Nonetheless, feel free to edit more if necessary.